# How to fix "After passing the service to the constructor of the component class, the web application does not working"

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I am developing a simple application using ASP.Net Core and Angular. There is a Web form with a drop-down list item. It is necessary to fill it with data from the database. After creating a simple form consisting of two "select" elements, everything is displayed normally. But after passing the service instance to the component class constructor, nothing is displayed on the form. What could be the reason?

The form was first created:

```html
<h1>New Vehicle</h1>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="make">Make</label>
    <select id="make" class="form-control">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let m of makes" value="{{m.Id}}">{{m.Name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="model">Model</label>
    <select id="model" class="form-control"></select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Next, a MakeService was created.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MakeService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getMakes(){
      return this.http.get('/api/makes')
        .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Registration the VehicleFormComponent and MakeService in app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './fetch-data/fetch-data.component';
import { VehicleFormComponent } from './vehicle-form/vehicle-form.component';
import { MakeService } from './services/make.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent,
    VehicleFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'vehicles/new', component: VehicleFormComponent },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    MakeService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
</i>

Implementation VehicleFormComponent
<i>import { MakeService } from '../services/make.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'vehicle-form',
    templateUrl: './vehicle-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./vehicle-form.component.css']
})
/** vehicle-form component*/
export class VehicleFormComponent implements OnInit {

  makes;

  /** vehicle-form ctor */
  constructor(private makeService: MakeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.makeService.getMakes().subscribe(makes => {
      this.makes = makes;
      console.log("MAKES", this.makes);
    });
    }
}
```

After starting the application, the form is empty.
[image]

If the component class is left empty:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'vehicle-form',
    templateUrl: './vehicle-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./vehicle-form.component.css']
})
/** vehicle-form component*/
export class VehicleFormComponent {

  /** vehicle-form ctor */
  constructor() { }
}
```

the form is displayed normally
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error in console. If so share the console error too.

Comment: yeah please share the error in console, if any

Comment: No console errors.

Comment: Did you get into the `api/makes`?And why does your url is empty in your first picture?